# An expression in Chandrasekhar's book on black holes does not make sense

Tags: black-holes, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

**Note:**

1. Book: The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes by Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar
2. $ \omega$ is a one-form and $X$ is a vector.
3. Commas denote partials derivative.

In Eq. (85), $ Y \langle \omega, X \rangle$ has been replaced by $Y^j (\omega_{k,j} X^k + \omega_k X^k_{,j}   )$.

Now as per Eq. (13),  $ \langle \omega, X \rangle$ is  the number obtained when the one-form $\omega$ acts on the vector $X$. Hence it should be $\omega_k X^k$. Why then Chandrasekhar replaces  $ Y \langle \omega, X \rangle$ by $Y^j (\omega_{k,j} X^k + \omega_k X^k_{,j}   )$, instead of $Y^j    \omega_k X^k  $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is not a multiplication of a vector field by a scalar function, but the application of a vector field as a derivative on the scalar function. In other words :

$$Y[\langle \omega, X \rangle] = Y^j \partial_j (\omega_k X^k) = Y^j (\omega_{k,j} X^k + \omega_k X^k_{,j})$$